# Unable to stop a setInterval on hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a hidden div that fades in on a jquery click method. This div has a slideshow that is powered by a simple setInterval, that unfortunately runs constantly on the hidden div. I'm struggling to make the setInterval start when I click to fadeIn the div and end when I click to hide it again. I need to make the interval run only whilst the div is showing.

This is what I have:

```
//3d Visualisation overlay containing slideshow
$('.overlay').hide();   
$('.vis1').click(function(){
    $('.visual-1').fadeIn(function(){;
        $('.close').click(function(){
            $('.visual-1').fadeOut();
        })
    });
});
//slideshow interval
$('.slideshow').hide(); 
$('.vis1').click(function(){
    var inter = setInterval(function() { 
        $('.slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(10)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(10)
            .end()
            .appendTo('.slideshow');
    },  4000);
}); 
$('.close').click(function(){
    clearInterval(inter);
});
```

The clearInterval here has also stopped the .close div from hiding the slideshow again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `inter` is not accessible from the `.close` click function. 
The code is quite confusing to me because you have 2 functions attached to a click event on the `.vis1` element.
So I just can tell you to declare `inter` outside of the function where you use the setInterval, so you can clear it on the `.close` element click handler.

Comment: Legend! Worked like a charm. Thanks.